# value echoing only last value in the array in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array with values from a table. When var_dumped it shows also the expected values in the array. But when it is echoed, value in the last array is echoed. How can I echo all the values that are present in the array. My view is as below:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">
               <div class="form-group">
            <label>Appoinment Date</label>
            <?php $attributes = array("name" => "Subscriptions add");
            echo form_open("Admin/show_appoinment", $attributes);?> 
            <div class="input-group date">
              <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </div> <input type="hidden" name="chair" value="1">
              <input type="date" name="n1" id="n1" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('n1'); ?>" onChange="copy();">
              </div>
               </div> </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 " style="margin-top:25px;">
     <input  type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info ">
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>

</div> 
<?php $temp_array=[]; foreach($list as $row){array_push($temp_array, $row['time'], $row['op_no']); } ?>    
<?php $attributes = array("name" => "Subscriptions add");
            echo form_open("Admin/Add_Appointment", $attributes);?> 

<?php $check=9.30; if(in_array($check, $temp_array)){ 

?>          
 <tbody  id="table1">
 <tr>
 <td class="bg-danger"><input type="text" name="time" class="form-control" id="Dept_Id" value="9.30" readonly></td>
 <td class="bg-danger"><input type="text"  class="form-control" value=" <?php echo $row['op_no']; ?> " readonly></td> 
 <td class="bg-danger"><input type="text"  class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $row['p_name'];?>" readonly>  </td> 
 <td class="bg-danger"><input type="text"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" readonly>  </td>  
 <td class="bg-danger"><input type="button" value="Booked" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger glyphicon col-sm-offset-0"> 
 <a href="<?php echo base_url('Admin/cancel_booking/'.$row['op_no'].'/'.$row['appointment_id']); ?>">  <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="s1" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning glyphicon col-sm-offset-0"></a></td>
   <?php } else{?>
   <td class="bg-success">
 <input type="hidden" name="chair" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="date" id="n2" value="<?php echo set_value('n1');?>"/>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" class="form-control" name="time" id="Dept_Id" value="9.30" readonly></td>
 <td class="bg-success"><input type="text" class="form-control"   name="op_no" id="op_no" value="" ></td>
 <td class="bg-success"><select name="p_name" class="form-control"  type="text"  id="p_name"/>
                <option></option>
                    <?php 

        foreach($patient->result() as $row)
        { 
          echo '<option value="'.$row->patient_id.'">'.$row->p_name.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
                </select></td>
<td class="bg-success"><select class="form-control"   name="dr_name"  type="text"  id="dr_name"/>
                <option></option>
                    <?php 
     foreach($chair->result() as $row)
        { 
          echo '<option value="'.$row->user_id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
        }
        ?></select></td>
<td class="bg-success">
<input type="submit" value="Booking" class="btn btn-sm btn-info glyphicon col-sm-offset-0"></td>
<?php } ?>

</tr>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

My Controller:

```
public function show_appoinment()
  {
  $date=$this->input->post('n1');
  $chair=$this->input->post('chair'); 
  $data['list']=$this->Appointment_model->get_appointment_by_date($date,$chair);
  $data['chai'] =$this->Appointment_model->getdoctors_chair();
  $data['chair'] =$this->Appointment_model->getdoctors_chair1($date); 
  $data['chairs'] =$this->Appointment_model->getdoctors_chair2($date);
  $data['patient'] =$this->Appointment_model->getpatient();
  $count['alert_count'] =  $this->Stock_model->get_stock_for_alert_msg();
  $this->load->view('Admin/header', $count);
  if($data['list']){ //var_dump($data['list']); die();
    $this->load->view('Admin/time_slot_view',$data);
   }
  else{
  $this->load->view('Admin/time_slot_view2',$data); 
  }
   $this->load->view('Admin/footer');
     }
```

My issue is: if I have two rows fetched from db in the array, when I try to echo these data one in the last row echoes repeatedly. How could I solve this..Please help.

Comment: echo '<option value="'.$row->patient_id.'">'.$row->p_name.'</option>';
Is this the line ,you are talking of?

Comment: @Ruby-That is the else part which also echoes along with the if part. My actual problem is if I have a booking at time 9.30, then it should echo the row and text field  with the patient details else it should echo the row to add the booking. How can it be possible.

Comment: I think I have to filter all the required data in the controller itself and pass it to the view.